# RegEx replace on condition only

Tags: regex, replace, conditional-statements

I use PCRE.

Sample input:

```
henri.superman@my.com:brainisapples
wholesorrow:delirium@my.com
```

Wanted output:

```
henri.superman@my.com:brainisapples
delirium@my.com:wholesorrow
```

I can capture both forms separately with:

```
^([^@]+):([^@]+@[^@]+)$
```

and

```
^([^@]+@[^@]+):([^@]+)$
```

But I can't figure out how to use $2:$1 replacement pattern only for first kind of strings.

Comment: If you are after `wholesorrow` exclusively you can inject that in your expression. Or would that not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REgex:

```
^([^@]+):([^@]+@[^@]+)$
```

REplace with:

```
\2:\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gH1xS7/1)

Comment: Yes, looks like that was just my tool bug. It doesn't output text that doesn't match replace pattern. Thank you, sir.